# nginx + uwsgi + django 502 bad gateway on aws ec2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, django, selinux, uwsgi

I have successfully installed nginx and uwsgi on aws ec2 instance. But on hitting the public IP its showing "502 bad gateway". Though both nginx and uwsgi server status is running and active.

The uwsgi.ini file is :

```
[uwsgi]

project_name = server

base_dir = /home/ec2-user/virt_env

virtualenv = %(base_dir)

chdir = %(base_dir)/server/

module =  %(project_name).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 4

# enable-threads  = true
# threads = 2

pidfile = django.uwsgi.pid

post-buffering = 204800

thunder-lock = True

uwsgi-socket = %(base_dir)/run/uwsgi.sock

chmod-socket = 666

socket-timeout = 300

reload-mercy = 8

reload-on-as = 512

harakiri = 50
max-requests = 5000

vacuum = true

disable-logging = True

logto = %(base_dir)/log/uwsgi.log

log-maxsize = 20971520

log-backupname = %(base_dir)/log/old-uwsgi.log

touch-reload = %(base_dir)/server/

# cpu-affinity = 1

max-worker-lifetime = 300
```

The uwsgi.service file is:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve updateMe project
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/virt_env/server/
Environment="PATH=/home/ec2-user/virt_env/"
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/virt_env/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/ec2-user/virt_env/server/conf/uwsgi.ini
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The nginx-uwsgi.conf file is:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:/home/ec2-user/virt_env/run/uwsgi.sock;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 13.234.37.103;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;
    location /media {
        alias /home/ec2-user/virt_env/server/media;
    }
    location /static {
         alias /home/ec2-user/virt_env/server/static;
    }
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass django
        uwsgi_read_timeout 300s;
        uwsgi_send_timeout 300s;
    }
    access_log /home/ec2-user/virt_env/log/dev-nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/ec2-user/virt_env/log/dev-nginx-error.log;
}
```

The errors in the log file are:

```
2019/04/23 05:51:07 [crit] 4338#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/ec2-user/virt_env/run/uwsgi.sock 
failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, 
client: 103.118.50.4, server: 13.234.37.103, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/ec2-user/virt_env/run/uwsgi.sock:", host: "13.234.37.103"
```

Also I have tried chmod-socket 664, 777 and changed sestatus (selinux) to enforcing, restarted psql, uwsgi, nginx services still it is showing 502 bad gateway error.

For selinux I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334526/nginx-cant-access-a-uwsgi-unix-socket-on-centos-7).

Comment: It's not good practice to put a web site's files in a user home directory. Move it somewhere more appropriate, such as a subdirectory of `/srv/www`.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. But will it address my problem?

Comment: In this case, probably so.

Comment: Thanks, but if you find the exact answer please post it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked on changing the directory to /srv/